# How long the messages will be kept stored in topic/partition using kafka 0.9

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm using a kafkaConsumer api to fetch data from topic (one partition per topic), after all records has been retrieved by poll method and processed, if a new instance of kafkaConsumer is created and try to fetch data from the same topic/partition then I'm able to retrieve the same data like in the first time. Is there any way to remove records from topic/partition after has been consumed ?

Comment: not necessary to remove them. you can assign the same group_id to the new consumer. also, you need to set the proper start offset for the new consumer. what kafka client are you using?

Comment: the messages can be stored for 1 week by default. you can set the time in config files

Comment: I'm using java client. Also I'm able to fetch data from an specific offset using seek method from kafkaConsumer, but the scenario that I want to achieve is fetch all the records just using poll method not manually using seek method, then if new records are added by kafkaProducer to topic then the consumer be able to fetch just the records recently added

Comment: did you try using the same group id. I did not work on java client. but I think it should work.

Comment: I found the root cause, if I force to commit offset using commitSync() method after data has been processed and set to false enable.auto.commit property then I will be able to fetch data that is never been consumed by kafkaConsumer. I did the following test, send 100 records thru kafkaProducer to topic/partition, then consume those records by kafkaConsumer, If I create a new instance of kafkaConsumer and try to fetch then there is not data to retrieve and the position (offset) of next record to fetch is 101

Comment: I got it. But auto.commit is enabled by default in Java client?

Comment: enable.auto.commit is true by default but AFAIK this property needs to be setting up and pass as an argument to the constructor of kafkaConsumer. Also using commitSync() commit offsets returned on the last poll() for all the subscribed list of topics and partitions.